# how to use db column name in regex_replace() - presto

Tags: sql, presto, regexp-replace

I am new to presto, I am looking to use regex_replace on a particular db column instead of a string.
E.g: Replace all entries from a column "Description" that starts with digit and followed by space from "table1"

Can someone please help with an example?

I tried this :

select(regexp_replace(col("Description"), '\d+\s')) from table1
but getting error: "Function not found", function "Col" is not registered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its enough to put column name and a replacement string should be added. So,

```
col("Description") -> Description
 -> ,'replace_string'
```

Final query should be something like this :

```
select regexp_replace(Description, '\d+\s','replace_string' ) from table1 b
```

Comment: Thanks!! This worked, appreciate your help!

Comment: @swapd where is my upvote :))))

Comment: Unfortunately I am not eligible to update, needs 15 reputations to upvote and I have only one :( I appreciate your timely help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(`Description`, '\d+\s')
FROM `table1`
```

They're optional in SQL, but you use backticks for column and table names, apostrophes for strings.

Comment: This is awesome!! Thanks for your help! backticks didn't worked for me but just column name with quotes did.